# Indent a string containing JSON like data

Tags: go

I have a string like below:

```
   "{out: \"world\", out2: \"hello\", employee: {name: \"Singh\", emailid: \"simran@yahoo.com gur@yahoo.com\", address: {street_name: \"xxxxxx\", old_address: {old_street_name: \"xxxxxx\"}}, emp_code: \"12345678\"}, array2: [\"first\", \"second\"]}"
```

I want to get output as below. I did try using Json.MarshalIndent() here https://play.golang.org/p/uJbkNS00__k but it is returning same string back without indenting it.

```
{
  "out": "world",
  "out2": "hello",
  "employee":
     {
      "name": "Singh",
      "emailid": "simran@yahoo.com gur@yahoo.com",
      "address":
         {
           "street_name": "xxxxxx",
           "old_address":
             {
               "old_street_name": "xxxxxx"
             }
         },
      "emp_code": "12345678"
     },
   "array2": ["first","second"]
}
```

Comment: That string is a quoted JSON string. If you want to indent the contents, you need to unquote/unmarshal it first.

Comment: Your example string isn't valid json to start with, and the example you have contains json in nested strings -- which are you trying to handle? If you have valid arbitrary json, just use 
https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json/?tab=doc#Indent

Comment: @Flimzy When I do `strconv.Unquote(st)`, I am getting empty string back. Can you paste an example using the same input string in https://play.golang.org. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JimB Sorry,  I didn't follow you. Why string is not valid json, because there are "\" es? What if we have strings like below?

`{employee: {emp_code: "12345678", name: "Gursimran Singh", emailid: "simran@yahoo.com gur@yahoo.com", address: {street_name: "xx xx xx", old_address: {old_street_name: "xx xxx"}}}, array2: ["first", "second"], out: "world", out2: "hello"}`

Could you please suggest on how to convert above input string?

Comment: @Gursimran: json does not allow unquoted keys, and you have unquoted keys. `Indent` works fine if you start with json: https://play.golang.org/p/phvyoLuvVeh

Comment: @JimB OMG! I didn't see those unquoted keys. I need to update my function to make keys quoted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JimB Yes it worked fine after making keys quoted. How the hell I missed this stupid mistake!! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use below function with little changes to remove '\' from JSON like string and then unmarshal it.

```
func StripSlashes(s string) string {
    s = strings.Replace(s, "\", "", -1)
    return s
}
```

Next, you can parson JSON string with [gjson](http://github.com/tidwall/gjson) library and use the gjson result. Or You can use the JSON.unmarshal(obj) from the stand Golang JSON library.

Comment: gjson is messing up the input. It is removing keys and making new key value pairs.